# Uber server_token

Tags: android, ios, uber-api

Does Uber server_token expires like access_token ?

> Note: Access tokens are valid for 30 days. The expiration time is specified in seconds in the ‘expires_in’ key of the token payload.

Can't find any documentation on server_token. TIA

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#api-token-authentication

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya What i want to know is , do i need to refresh it like access token ? & also does server_token expires after few days ?

Comment: `does server_token expires after few days` YES

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya is it stated somewhere in the documentation ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya How long will it last ?

Comment: refresh_token and server_token will not expire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the server_token does not expire. The only way it can be changed is by generating a new one in your dashboard.

Comment: Is it mentioned anywhere in the Doc ? I couldn't find it :(

Comment: It was really confusing to me at first as the docs don't even say it themselves. I just had to assume it as the docs only say that the access_token expires :(

Comment: are you using server_token in your app ? if so , how long have you been using it ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using server_token in my app. I've been using the same one for around a month now. Works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks . They should mention it in the Doc!!

Comment: No problem! And yeah, it's super confusing for beginners. They need to update their docs. Same with the lyft api!

Answer (score 1):

From official guideline **[Uber Authentication](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#api-token-authentication)**

```
    {
    "access_token": "xxx",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 2592000,
    "refresh_token": "xxx",
    "scope": "profile history"
  }
```

> The access_token is good for a **`limited period`** of time described by
>   expires_in seconds. The **`refresh_token does not expire`** and can be used
>   to obtain a new access_token at any time given that the calling
>   application is still authorized to access the API on behalf of this
>   user.

Comment: Please read the question once , i'm asking about server token which different from access_token and refresh_token . Server token will be there in Dashboard.

Comment: @Shahal like `refresh_token `server_token does not expire .

Comment: refresh_token do expire. 
"A refresh_token is valid for one year and tokens that have been inactive for more than one year will be invalidated."